# Sending images to angular client in spring boot rest api?

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-boot

I am developing a rest api using spring boot. 
I have an upload image service which stores images in my project workspace and image url in stored in db.
I have an entity product which has a list of images. Now I have to return images back to the angular client.

I have two questions in mind:

Q1. Should I return just a list of image urls to the client? If yes how should client render images from those urls.

Q2. OR Should I return list of images itself? If yes please show me logic which is fast and efficient.

Q3. OR Should I return individual image one by one? If yes please tell me how.

Update:

Note: Since, Rest api is on one machine and Angular client is on another machine. I think that the image url needs some kind of prefix:

Suppose my project is in E:/myproject/ and images are in E:/myproject/images/image-name.jpg, so what should be prefix for image url.

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. Should I return just a list of image urls to the client? If yes how should client render images from those urls.

**THIS**. Since all you need to do next is to give those urls `<img src="something.png" />` tags in the front end. This will also free the server from the responsibility of downloading the image and service it to the clients.

> Q2. OR Should I return list of images itself? If yes please show me logic which is fast and efficient.

This is possible but very hard. I don't advise doing this since this will make the system download the image twice: first is from file storage to the backend, then 2nd is from backend to frontend.

> Q3. OR Should I return individual image one by one? If yes please tell me how.

This is the approach you need to do if the images needs individual security when downloading. Securing your image downloads is possible with the 1st approach that you given, and again, this approach will make you download the image twice.

Answer (score 3):

Q1. Should I return just a list of image urls to the client? If yes how should client render images from those urls.

Ans : Return the list of urls to angular . Angular will use this code.

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images">
   <img src={{image.ImagePath}} />
</div>
```

It will automatically fetch the images present at the url path

Comment: Ans for Que2 :-  I think this is possible. But It will not be the efficient way

Comment: Ans for Que 3:- If you have List of images then passing one by one is not the efficient way. Imagine you have to pass 100 images then you have to call api 100 times. So better you collect required image urls in one list and pass it to the frontend

Comment: @Aakashkharat I have updated the question, please take a look at the update.

Comment: @Aakashkharat it is not working. Since API and client are on separate machines, the image-URL API returns would refer to the local storage of angular client machine.

Comment: @ShafqatShafi Sorry I missed that updated part in your question . I'll add comment when I find some solution for your problem

Comment: @Aakashkharat it will work if the client and server are on the same machine. but if we have different clients on different machines it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

```java
private static final Map<String, MediaType> TYPE_MAP = new HashMap();

    static {
        TYPE_MAP.put("pdf", MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        TYPE_MAP.put("gif", MediaType.IMAGE_GIF);
        TYPE_MAP.put("jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        TYPE_MAP.put("jpeg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        TYPE_MAP.put("png", MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        TYPE_MAP.put("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
        TYPE_MAP.put("xls", MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
        TYPE_MAP.put("xlsx", MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"));
    }



@GetMapping(value = "/preview")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> previewFile(@RequestParam String filePath) {
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(Paths.get(filePath).toUri());
        String fileName = testFile.png;
        String extension = png;
        MediaType mediaType = TYPE_MAP.getOrDefault(extension,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .contentType(mediaType)
                .body(file);
    }
```

Send filePath to the angular client and use this service in order to preview that file.

Comment: Its nice of you to post answer that supports multiple file extensions. But I am already doing this. The down side of this approach is it will need more service calls depending on number of images of a product instead of 1. If you have better approach please suggest it.

Comment: @ShafqatShafi Then put images on some path and write `nginx` rule to access these images. And send those paths to your client. btw Thanks for your compliment.